# LWUIT ArrayOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I am new to LWUIT, and even though I am finding it very interesting to use, I have been having the challenge of previewing whatever `MIDlet` I generate.  Each time i run the `MIDlet` in an emulator, I get an `ArrayOutOfBOundException` displaying as a form on the screen of the emulator and will only leave after pressing OK on the form.

This is my code

```
    import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.*;
    import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;
    import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
    import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.UIManager;
    import com.sun.lwuit.util.Resources;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Ruwwa extends MIDlet implements ActionListener {
      public void startApp() {
       Display.init(this);

    Form f = new Form("");

    f.setTitle("Mairuwa Portal");

    Label bottomText = new Label();
    bottomText.setText("Welcome to the Mairuwa Portal");
    bottomText.setTextPosition(Component.CENTER);
    f.addComponent(bottomText);

    Command exitCommand = new Command("Exit");
    f.addCommand(exitCommand);
    f.addCommandListener(this);

    f.show();

    try {
      Resources r = Resources.open("/res/working.res");
       UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("Mairuwa Theme"));
         } catch (IOException ioe) {
             // Do something here.
         }

    }

    public void pauseApp() {}

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
       Label label = new Label();
       label.setText("Initiating IO, please wait...");
       Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // perform IO operation...
      }
    });
    label.setText("IO completed!");
     // update UI...
      }
    }
```

It displayed the form with this code but it didnt display it on the theme i created.The name of the theme is "working.res" and i included it in a res folder in the project folder.Thanx

Comment: Show us your code and we might be able to help

Answer (score 1):

While im running your code im getting `illegalargumentexception` on this line, `bottomText.setTextPosition(Component.CENTER);`.

Because you can't set the label text position as `Component.CENTER`. You should use the label text position as `LEFT/RIGHT/BOTTOM/TOP`. If you change the label text position as I mentioned, it will work properly.

So If you getting `ArrayOutOfBOundException`, you did a mistake on some other place. Try to debug your application and find out where did you made a mistake.

**Update:**

```
Display.init(this);
try {
      Resources r = Resources.open("/res/working.res");
       UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("Mairuwa Theme"));
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
          // Do something here.
     }
   // your code.
```

Comment: I did what you told me as mentioned.The problem i am having is that the LABEL actually did show but it didnt appear on theme.The theme didnt appear at all.I cant get to put the label on theme,and other gui components.thanx

Comment: You called `Resource` after showing the `Form`. Its wrong. Try to call the `Resource` below of the `Display.init(this);`. Look on my update.

Comment: The path to the theme is probably incorrect as well. If the theme is in the root of the jar it should be / not /res.

Comment: @ Shai, If we added the `res` folder in Libraries and properties, it should work. Right?